# How to return a modification on the input when a function that produces a new output is called in it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have two functions: `reverseArray` for creating a *new* array in which the elements are reversed in order, and `reverseArrayInPlace` for *modifying* an array. However, my second function, which makes a call on the first function doesn't modify the array, but creates a new one. I don't understand why `array = reverseArray(array);` line doesn't ensure that.

```
let ab = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]; 


// Function to create a new array with elements sorted in reverse:
function reverseArray(array) {
    let newAr = [];
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        newAr.push(array[i])
    }
    return newAr;
}

// Function to modify an array with elements sorted in reverse:
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
    array = reverseArray(array);
    return array;
}
```

Comment: You're not modifying the referenced array, you're just overwriting the variable that holds it. For what it's worth, [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) already reverses an array in place.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nnbwui ...it works..

Comment: @UthistranSelvaraj That isn't *"in place*". In your example, `output === ab` should return `true`.

Comment: @TylerRoper how output=== ab returns true . it is false in my case

Comment: @UthistranSelvaraj Exactly. You're creating a *new array*. OP wants to modify the *existing array*. Take a peek at Nina's answer below and you can see that `ab` is re-used.

Comment: @Tyler Can you elaborate it more please and show me the right way to modify the referenced array?

Comment: @OmerT Nina's answer below does that. Otherwise, you could just do `ab.reverse()`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look to your function.

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
    array = reverseArray(array);
    return array;
}
```

Your function has a variable `array` as parameter and by calling the function an object reference is handed over for not primitive data types, like objects, functions and special form of objects, like arrays.

By assigning a new array, later in the code, you store the reference to a local variable and the original variable with the *original array/the object reference to it* stays the same. Only the local reference has changed.

---

You need to keep the same object reference.

In this case, you could empty the array and push the new reversed values.

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
    let newAr = [];
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        newAr.push(array[i])
    }
    return newAr;
}


function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
    var temp = reverseArray(array);
    array.length = 0;
    array.push(...temp);
    return array;
}

let ab = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]; 

console.log(...ab);
reverseArrayInPlace(ab);
console.log(...ab);
```

Comment: Yes it works, but I still don't understand the difference. Why doesn't assigning a new value to a variable change the variable as in `array = reverseArray(array);`?

Comment: Can we have a live chat please? I am still confused.

Comment: you could come to this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206815/talk

Answer (score 0):

your functions work the wrong way around

```
let ab = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]; 

//Function to create a new array with elements sorted in reverse:
function reverseArray(array) {
  // reverse in playce, a copy of the input array
  return reverseArrayInPlace(array.slice());

  // or copy and reverse in a single loop
  //let newAr = Array(array.length);
  //for (let i = 0, j=array.length-1; j >= 0; ++i, --j) {
  //  newAr[i] = array[j];
  //}
  //return newAr;
}

// Function to modify an array with elements sorted in reverse:
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for(let i=0, j=array.length-1; i<j; ++i, --j) {
    let tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;
  }
  return array;
}
```